# create folder using a form with a given name

Tags: forms, mkdir

Im trying to make a html form that can create a folder on the server with a given name in the html form. So fare I have this code:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['createDir'])) {
    //get value of inputfield
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'. var_dump($_POST)];
    //set the target path ??
    $targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true); //create the directory
    }
}

print_r($_POST); exit;
?>




<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" name="myform" id="myform">
<input  name="dirname" id="dirname" >    
<input type="submit" name="dirname" value="dirname" title="Continue to the next step">
</form>
```

The debug say: Array ( )

the script is nothing i have wrote but trying to put thing together to get it working but have not fix this for days now. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use PHP short opening tags (`<?`). Use the long form (`<?php`). You risk getting tangled up in the wrong language processor.
2. You're looking for `$_POST['createDir']` coming back from the form, but I don't see a form element with `name="createDir"`.
3. What is `$_POST['dirname'. var_dump($_POST)]` supposed to do?
4. What is PATH?
5. Play it safe by giving a `type=` for `dirname` input element.